# Inverted grep search with a pattern file?

Tags: linux, grep, pattern-matching

I'm using `grep` with an inverted search (`-v`) to remove lines from a user file that I don't want to keep. As the pattern changes, I want to use a pattern file to grab the pattern that needs to be removed. However, it's failing and I don't know why.

This works perfectly:

```
grep -v -F 'removethisstring' inputfile > newfile
```

`newfile` is correct, the pattern line is now removed from the file.

However, putting the pattern in a file it fails:

```
grep -v -F -f patternfile inputfile > newfile
```

`newfile` is unchanged, the line with the pattern is still there.  What am I doing wrong?

*inputfile*

```
grapes are purple
hello fox in the house
bonnet is blue
simple is best
```

*patternfile*

```
fox
```

*newfile result:*

(same as inputfile)

*desired output*

```
grapes are purple
bonnet is blue
simple is best
```

Comment: Works for me. Give us a [small example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Still works for me. Do you have stray whitespace somewhere? Do both files end with a newline (NOT an empty line, just a newline (`\n`) character)?

Comment: I cannot repro this, either: http://ideone.com/emDI3t

Comment: Well its happening here on Centos. I've checked for whitespace and /n kevin, thanks

Comment: try once by splitting the command in two part.. x=(grep -v -F 'removethisstring' inputfile) then echo "$x" > newfile..

Comment: I want to execute it with the pattern file. How do I split it into two? thank you...

Comment: Check your pattern file for special characters: `cat -A patternfile` or `cat -v patternfile`.

Comment: cat -A patternfile
fox^M$
[root@u184508]# cat -v patternfile
fox^M

Comment: So your pattern file has a DOS carriage return.  Close as typo.  This is an extremely common mistake and one of the many reasons we recommend you don't use Windows to edit Unix files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running dos2unix on patternfile before using to remove control M characters and check.